# setFileName in MimeBodyPart required?

Tags: java

Is it really required to set a **FileName** in **MimeBodyPart** while adding an image?

The answer to this question is already addressed in somewhere means, kindly please relink me to that answer. I couldn't find. Thanks in advance.

This is my code.

```
MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource((byte[] image, "image/jpeg");
bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
bodyPart.setContentID(<some id>);
bodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
bodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
```

Like this I am adding 3 more images to send an SMTP mail. But Is it required to add the file Name  (i.e) [bodyPart.setFileName(fileName);] for every image?

Comment: You need to provide more context to your question, because it depends on the structure of your message iirc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can you check now? I updated my question.

Comment: Did you try without a filename, did it work?